# Playing Taxi With Friends

Tags: debit-card

I have friends who ask for rides from time to time and it makes me feel like I'm a taxi on occasion.  Can I use Square and just have them use their debit card for a charge?

Comment: Venmo would be a better fit

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking.  Is it if you can have a service taxi your friends instead of you?  Is it if you can use a service to bill your friends for your services?  Is it something else that I didn't see?  Also, how does this connect to personal finance?

Comment: If you want to lose friends...  Of course, if they are the sort of friends who expect you to do things for them with no reciprocity, maybe you do want to lose them :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Square, if you can convince them to pay. You should declare that as income, though... Personally, if you don't want to do it as a friend, I'd suggest simply saying "sorry, I'm busy."